# Why does subprocess Popen halt the script that started the subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, discord.py, popen

Trying to get input from my discord server and have it open/close a minecraft server on my computer via this function:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    messageContent = message.content
    response = ListenServerCommands(messageContent)
    if response is not None:
        await message.channel.send(response)
```

and then in the script where `ListenServerCommand()` is defined:

```
def ListenServerCommands(input_):
    if input_ == "start":
        start()
        return "Server starting"
    if input_ == "stop":
        stop()
        return "Server stopping"
```

```
def start():
    if not status():
        os.chdir(minecraftDir)
        serverProcess = subprocess.Popen('"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_251\\bin\\java.exe" -Xms4G -Xmx4G -jar server.jar nogui java', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

When I type start into the discord the, server starts up. However, the rest of the script where `ListenServerCommands()` is defined halts. And while the output of the minecraft server does not show up in the terminal, all of the input within that terminal goes to the minecraft server. I would like the script that is halting to still be able to handle the input from discord so that when someone types "stop" the script can kill the subprocess.

Comment: You likely should be using an async process executor https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#subprocesses

Comment: It's not clear how you are determining that your script is blocked, but I will note that you are opening a pipe between your program and the Minecraft server for its output, but never read from that pipe, so the server will block if it tries to write to a full pipe buffer. Nothing else in the code you've shown should block if the server blocks, though.